# MYSQL - How to join two queries to omit elements found in the second query (or perhaps any better solution?)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join, logic

I have a wordpress database with a number of custom fields/metadata.

```
---------
wp_postmeta
---------
post_id
meta_key
meta_value
```

I want to find all the posts with a meta_key of 'Start Date' and a value of 'NOW()', but not the posts that have the meta_key 'Ongoing' and value of 'Yes'.

I'm a bit confused of how to join the queries:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Start Date'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value > NOW()
```

with

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Ongoing'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value != 'Yes'
```

And potentially other queries... I think what is throwing me off is that I can't add another WHERE clause to the statement? I think I just need a prod in the right direction because I am missing some basic mysql understanding.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question but when meta_key is 'State Date' obviously it can't be 'Ongoing' at the same time, so there will be no rows with meta_key = 'Ongoing' in your results to filter out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
AND ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Start Date'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value > NOW()) OR (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Ongoing'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value != 'Yes'))
```

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to work but I had issues when trying to apply a sort order to the 'Start Date' meta_key. Where could one apply a ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_key?

Is there any reason this would be a better solution than the NOT IN solution below?

Comment: I think that's it's cleaner and, in my opinion, might be faster as the database grows. For the Order by just add:  ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_key at the very end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I remember being there. You don't want to know the unscalable, convoluted solution I came up with.

You're just looking for a couple of paren's and an [`AND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html) with a [`NOT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html).

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
 -- parens make sure everything is grouped correctly and you don't have "and
 -- meta_key - Ongoing and meta_value > NOW()
(wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Start Date'
 AND wp_postmeta.meta_value > NOW())
-- these conditions are all mutually exclusive, so they could never 
-- simultaneously exist.
AND NOT
(wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Ongoing'
 AND wp_postmeta.meta_value != 'Yes')
```

**IF you wanted to combine the results**, you have the option of using `OR`. Just replace the `AND NOT` with an `OR` and see what happens.

You can also use `UNION` (though that is almost never done when `OR` is an option (I do seem to remember that there can be subtle performance differences, but worrying about that is often premature optimization)):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Start Date'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value > NOW()
-- Distinct vs. ALL is not really relevant here because you can't have overlap
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Ongoing'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value != 'Yes'
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, unfortunately I kept getting syntax errors with the (AND ...). You are right about needing to use parentheses though, can't believe I overlooked something so obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Start Date'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value > NOW() and wp_posts.ID NOT IN (select post_id from wp_postmeta
where wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Ongoing' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'Yes')
```